# How can I create PHP SOAP request to call web service implemented in ColdFusion

Tags: php, web-services, soap, coldfusion, soap-client

I have implemented web service in ColdFusion. I am trying to call that webservice using php. But getting errors.

Can someone help me to prepare SAOP request in php? xml request is below in SOAP UI.

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://localhost:8501/webservice">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:ASK soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
     <AgentID> 1 </AgentID> 
   <Passwd> 12345 </Passwd> 
          <TransactionNumber >XXX </TransactionNumber > 
          <Sign >XXX </Sign > 
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have used below code in php

$soapUrl = "http://domain.com/webservice/transaction.cfc?WSDL"; // asmx URL of WSDL

```html
$xml_post_string = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://localhost:8501/webservice">
                        <soapenv:Header/>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                           <web:ASK soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
                                     <AgentID> 1 </AgentID> 
                                     <Passwd> 12345 </Passwd> 
                               <TransactionNumber >XXX </TransactionNumber > 
                               <Sign >XXX </Sign > 
                     </soapenv:Body>
                     </soapenv:Envelope>';
```

```
    $xml_array['AgentID'] = '1';
    $xml_array['Passwd'] = "12345";
    $xml_array['TransactionNumber'] = "XXX";


    $client = new SoapClient($soapUrl, array( 'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1, 'trace'=>1));

    $xml=   $client-> ASK($xml_array,$soapUrl,"POST",0);
 (OR) 
    $xml=   $client-> ASK($xml_post_string ,$soapUrl,"POST",0);

              print "<pre>";
             print_r($xml);
             print "</pre>";
    ?>
```

Returns below error in both case

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Server.userException] No such operation 'ASK' in C:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Comment: Output of  var_dump($client->__getFunctions()) is like this-  array(8) { [0]=> string(31) "anyType getDate(string $t_date)" [1]=> string(13) "UNKNOWN PUT()" [2]=> string(13) "UNKNOWN RES()" [3]=> string(60) "anyType userAuthinticate(string $AGENT_ID, string $password)" [4]=> string(13) "UNKNOWN UPD()" [5]=> string(13) "UNKNOWN PAY()" [6]=> string(13) "UNKNOWN ASK()" [7]=> string(13) "UNKNOWN DEL()" }